# Monotouch.Dialog IOS 6 Split view Rotation issue

Tags: ios, xamarin.ios, ios6, monotouch.dialog, autorotate

BUMP .. still havent figured this out, the thing rotates, but out of view. so weird. 
can i provide better information to get help?

STILL HAVING THIS ISSUE! its really bad i cant fix this :( help PLEASE

BUMP .. please im dieing here! someone anyone! :)

So, I'm using `Monotouch.Dialog` and since IOS 6, the rotation of my splitview controller is acting weird.

It is actually rotating, but my detail view takes up the whole screen and the master view seems as if its being rotated off the screen frame. That is, I can see the master view for a split second when it rotates then it's gone, and the detail view takes the whole screen.

I've added the necessary `ShouldAutorotate` function and set the `GetSupportedInterfaceOrientations` since IOS 6. Like I said it rotates, but something is just off.

I've tried the IOS 5 simulator and it works, so it's definitely an IOS 6 problem.

Anyone have an idea where else I should look for the problem?

EDIT: I noticed while debugging that it doesnt go into the ShouldAutorotate override of my master and detail view, only in my split view controller it goes in. In iOS 5 it goes into ShouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation properly.

Here is the code i use in my Detail and Master views:

```
public override bool ShouldAutorotate()
    {
        return true;
    }
    [Obsolete]
    public override bool ShouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation       (MonoTouch.UIKit.UIInterfaceOrientation toInterfaceOrientation)
    {
        return true;
    }
```

And here is the code i have in my SplitViewController:

```
public override bool ShouldAutorotate()
    {
        return true;
    }

    [Obsolete]
    public override bool ShouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation(UIInterfaceOrientation requested)
    {
        return requested == UIInterfaceOrientation.LandscapeRight || requested == UIInterfaceOrientation.LandscapeLeft;
        //return requested == UIInterfaceOrientation.Portrait || requested == UIInterfaceOrientation.PortraitUpsideDown;

    }

    public override bool ShouldAutomaticallyForwardRotationMethods {
        get {
            return true;
        }
    }
```

anyone please? i need this for my work and i cant solve this! any ideas would be helpful!

Comment: I noticed that the ShouldAutoRotate is getting called on my split view Controller but not on the detail and master view controllers. I use a UITableViewController for the detail view and a UINavigationController for the master view.

Answer (score 0):

It's difficult to guess what's wrong without seeing the code itself. It's likely working on iOS 5.x because it will be calling the old [`shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIViewController_Class/DeprecationAppendix/AppendixADeprecatedAPI.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIViewController/shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation%3a) selector (and because your application and/or MonoTouch.Dialog already supports that).

This is **deprecated** in iOS6 - but it will still be called **for backward compatibility** unless you implement it's replacements. Note the plural form *replacements*, from Apple doc:

> Override the supportedInterfaceOrientations and preferredInterfaceOrientationForPresentation methods instead.)

The deprecation notices does not mean iOS6 won't work with the older API. It's a remainder that some new, better, API were added and that the old API *could be* removed in some future iOS release (removals have been so far very uncommon).

Note: I do encourage you to stop using old API from iOS versions you do not support (e.g. something deprecated in iOS 4.0 should be be used in applications supporting 5.0 and later only). However duplicating code to support both 5.0 and 6.0 *best* API might not be a good idea unless you gain something out of it (e.g. new functionalities).

Most of the new API, deprecating older API, are meant to make your life easier, not harder.

Comment: well its certainly making it harder right now hehe ... but if it wasnt working, the rotation, because of IOS6 the device wouldnt even rotate, which it does. What could cause it to rotate the detail view out of the screen?

Comment: this is what I'm using in my detail and master view: public override void DidRotate (UIInterfaceOrientation fromInterfaceOrientation)
  {
   base.DidRotate (fromInterfaceOrientation);

   this.TableView.SelectRow(lastSelectedQuestion, false, UITableViewScrollPosition.Middle);
  }
  
  public override bool ShouldAutorotate()
  {
   return true;
  }
  [Obsolete]
  public override bool ShouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation (MonoTouch.UIKit.UIInterfaceOrientation toInterfaceOrientation)
  {
   return true;
  }

Comment: and this i have in the split view controller:                                public override bool ShouldAutorotate()
  {
   return true;
  }
  [Obsolete]
  public override bool ShouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation(UIInterfaceOrientation requested)
  {
   return requested == UIInterfaceOrientation.LandscapeRight || requested == UIInterfaceOrientation.LandscapeLeft;
   //return requested == UIInterfaceOrientation.Portrait || requested == UIInterfaceOrientation.PortraitUpsideDown;
   
  }
  public override bool ShouldAutomaticallyForwardRotationMethods {
   get {
    return true;
   }
  }

Comment: Please edit your original question. That will be a lot easier to read and many more people will see it (than just me).

Answer (score 0):

Also don't forget to set `window.rootViewController` (otherwise rotation will not work on the iPad).