# Orientation sensitive iOS App with MonoTouch

Tags: xamarin.ios

I'm currently trying to build an iOS app which is orientation sensitive - when I rotate the app, I want the view to change.

```
public override bool ShouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation (UIInterfaceOrientation toInterfaceOrientation)
    {           
        new UIAlertView("DEBUG", "test", null, "OK", null).Show ();

        // Return true for supported orientations
        if (UserInterfaceIdiomIsPhone) {
            return (toInterfaceOrientation != UIInterfaceOrientation.PortraitUpsideDown);
        } else {
            return true;
        }
    }
```

I inserted the UIAlert to test if this is actually detected, but unfortunately not. I was wondering if I may get any advice on this please?

Comment: possible duplicate of [shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation is not working in iOS 6](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12577879/shouldautorotatetointerfaceorientation-is-not-working-in-ios-6)

Answer (score 0):

Apple changed the rotation api in ios6 - see [Monotouch.Dialog IOS 6 Split view Rotation issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12805250/monotouch-dialog-ios-6-rotation-issue) for some more help (including some MonoTouch)